Which PHP package is correct one
I'm about to install LAMP on Ubuntu 24 LTS. I see that in Ubuntu I can install PHP modules in two ways.
sudo apt install php8.3-mysql
which outputs
The following additional packages will be installed:
  php-common php8.3-common
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  php-common php8.3-common php8.3-mysql

or
sudo apt install php-mysql
which displays
The following additional packages will be installed:
  php-common php8.3-common php8.3-mysql
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  php-common php-mysql php8.3-common php8.3-mysql

Is the php-mysql an alias for the package default to the current Ubuntu version?
Are there any benefits or downsides of one or another approach?

Try apt-cache show php-mysql and it directly tells you the answer in the Description.

difference between php-mysql and php8.3-mysql
root@raspberrypi:~# apt show php-mysql
Package: php-mysql
Version: 2:7.4+76
Priority: optional
Section: php
Source: php-defaults (76)
Maintainer: Debian PHP Maintainers <team+pkg-php@tracker.debian.org>
Installed-Size: 13.3 kB
Depends: php-common, php7.4-mysql
Download-Size: 6,360 B
APT-Sources: http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main arm64 Packages
Description: MySQL module for PHP [default]
 This package provides a MySQL module for PHP.
 .
 PHP (recursive acronym for PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor) is a widely-used
 open source general-purpose scripting language that is especially suited
 for web development and can be embedded into HTML.
 .
 This package is a dependency package, which depends on Debian's default
 PHP version (currently 7.4).


php-mysqlpackage installs the latest stable version which is currently available And set by the developer of the distribution to the stable branch.
That means that it is mostly not the current and up to date as also latest available version.
while php8.3-mysql install php8.3 with php8.3-mysql and needs to be enabled and used specifically.
